# Working with columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a part of the table which I have:

```
type  n_b
sp     2
sp     2
sp     3
avn    2
avn    4
avn    3
psp    1
psp    3
psp    5
...
```

Also I have a data set:

```
d = pd.Series({'sp':['98,00', '0,00', '68,00'], 'psp':['17,00',  '7,60', '14,30'], 
           'avn':['15,00', '10,00', '4,30']})
```

I need to match the value from my data set in a new column "c_t" depending on the value in the column "type". That's what should be the result:

```
type  n_b    c_t
sp     2    98,00
sp     2     0,00
sp     3    68,00
avn    2    15,00
avn    4    10,00
avn    3     4,30
psp    1    17,00
psp    3     7,60
psp    5    14,30
...
```

My code looks like this:

```
d = pd.Series({'sp':['98,00', '0,00', '68,00'], 'psp':['17,00',  '7,60', '14,30'], 
           'avn':['15,00', '10,00', '4,30']})

df['c_t'] = df['type'].map(d)
print (df)
```

But it does not work as I need it

```
type  n_b    c_t
sp     2    [98,00, 0,00, 68,00]
sp     2    [98,00, 0,00, 68,00]
sp     3    [98,00, 0,00, 68,00]
avn    2    [15,00, 10,00, 4,30]
avn    4    [15,00, 10,00, 4,30]
avn    3    [15,00, 10,00, 4,30]
psp    1    [17,00, 7,60, 14,30]
psp    3    [17,00, 7,60, 14,30]
psp    5    [17,00, 7,60, 14,30]
...
```

How can I fix this?

UPD: In fact, there is much more data in the file

```
d1 = pd.Series({'ds':['104,50', '19,00', '10,00', '30,00', '0,00', '0,00', '16,00', '21,50'],
           'zkp':['33,00', '100,00', '16,00', '3,30', '9,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '4,80', '78,50'],
           'dgv':['96,00', '0,00', '194,50', '61,00', '0,00', '10,00', '0,00', '28,00', '0,00', '0,00', 
                       '11,00', '30,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '16,00', '78,50'], 'sp':['98,00', '0,00', '68,00'],
           'psp':['17,00', '7,60', '14,30'],'avn':['15,00', '10,00', '4,30']})
```

And the table is huge:

```
type  n_b Day_number
ds     2     1
ds     3     2
ds     1     3
ds     2     4
ds     1     5
ds     3     6
ds     2     7
ds     1     8
sp     2     1
sp     2     2
sp     1     3
avn    2     1
avn    4     2
avn    3     3
psp    1     1
psp    3     2
psp    5     3
sp     2     1
sp     2     2
sp     4     3
...
```

And all types(ds, zkp, dgv, sp, psp, avn) are in the file. The column "n_b" does not affect the column "c_t". In the column "Day_number" numbered days, if it helps.

And the result should be the following:

```
 type  n_b Day_number      c_t
ds     2     1           104,50
ds     3     2            19,00
ds     1     3            10,00
ds     2     4            30,00
ds     1     5             0,00
ds     3     6             0,00
ds     2     7            16,00
ds     1     8            21,50
sp     2     1            98,00
sp     2     2             0,00
sp     1     3            68,00
avn    2     1            15,00  
avn    4     2            10,00
avn    3     3             4,30
psp    1     1            17,00  
psp    3     2             7,60
psp    5     3            14,30
sp     2     1            98,00
sp     2     2             0,00
sp     4     3            68,00
...
```

Comment: Does n_b have any bearing on the placement of the data set or is it always just going to be in the order in which it appears in the Series? And will there always be 3 types in a row?

Comment: No, the column "n_b" does not affect the placement of data. The number of types in a row may be different. But I define it in advance. I just thought that if I had an example, I could do it on other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `DataFrame` from `lists` first, then create helper columns `g` with unique values per group with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to `df`:

```
#get lenghts of lists
l = d.str.len()
#repeat index values by lengths
r = np.repeat(d.index.values, l)
#flattening lists
v = np.concatenate(d.values)
#DataFrame constructor
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'type':r, 'c_t':v})
print (df1)
     c_t type
0  15,00  avn
1  10,00  avn
2   4,30  avn
3  17,00  psp
4   7,60  psp
5  14,30  psp
6  98,00   sp
7   0,00   sp
8  68,00   sp

df1['g'] = df1.groupby('type').cumcount()
df['g'] = df.groupby('type').cumcount()

df = df.join(df1.set_index(['type','g']), on=['type','g']).drop('g', axis=1)
print (df)
   ype  n_b    c_t
0   sp    2  98,00
1   sp    2   0,00
2   sp    3  68,00
3  avn    2  15,00
4  avn    4  10,00
5  avn    3   4,30
6  psp    1  17,00
7  psp    3   7,60
8  psp    5  14,30
```

EDIT:

```
d1 = pd.Series({'ds':['104,50', '19,00', '10,00', '30,00', '0,00', '0,00', '16,00', '21,50'],
           'zkp':['33,00', '100,00', '16,00', '3,30', '9,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '4,80', '78,50'],
           'dgv':['96,00', '0,00', '194,50', '61,00', '0,00', '10,00', '0,00', '28,00', '0,00', '0,00', 
                       '11,00', '30,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '16,00', '78,50'], 'sp':['98,00', '0,00', '68,00'],
           'psp':['17,00', '7,60', '14,30'],'avn':['15,00', '10,00', '4,30']})
```

---

```
#get lenghts of lists
l = d1.str.len()
#repeat index values by lengths
r = np.repeat(d1.index.values, l)
#flattening lists
v = np.concatenate(d1.values)
#DataFrame constructor
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'type':r, 'c_t':v})
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('type').cumcount() + 1

df = df.join(df1.set_index(['type','g']), on=['type','Day_number'])
print (df)
   type  n_b  Day_number     c_t
0    ds    2           1  104,50
1    ds    3           2   19,00
2    ds    1           3   10,00
3    ds    2           4   30,00
4    ds    1           5    0,00
5    ds    3           6    0,00
6    ds    2           7   16,00
7    ds    1           8   21,50
8    sp    2           1   98,00
9    sp    2           2    0,00
10   sp    1           3   68,00
11  avn    2           1   15,00
12  avn    4           2   10,00
13  avn    3           3    4,30
14  psp    1           1   17,00
15  psp    3           2    7,60
16  psp    5           3   14,30
17   sp    2           1   98,00
18   sp    2           2    0,00
19   sp    4           3   68,00
```

Comment: Thank you! But the code has worked only for one value. In other rows there is NaN. Whether it is possible to correct it?

Comment: One value? I dont understand. Can you explain it?

Comment: I updated the question. In my case, it only works for the first value  'dgv'. That is, the column "c_t" looks like this:                                  96,00  
0,00  
194,50  
61,00  
0,00  
10,00  
0,00  
28,00  
0,00  
0,00  
11,00  
30,00  
0,00  
0,00  
0,00  
16,00  
78,50  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
and so on

Comment: Sorry, Iam not sure if understand. I try your new data and works perfectly. I reuse your `Day_number` column in `join`, so one `cumcount` is removed. There is something wrong?

Comment: It simply create new `df1` dataframe and data in lists are converted to column. Then iis necessary `cumcount` for count groups, because duplicates and left join is not possible. So I add new column and then join 2 columns with 2 columns.

Comment: Glad can help you, nice day!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're almost there. You've now got:

```
df
Out[758]: 
  type  n_b                   c_t
0   sp    2  [98,00, 0,00, 68,00]
1   sp    2  [98,00, 0,00, 68,00]
2   sp    3  [98,00, 0,00, 68,00]
3  avn    2  [15,00, 10,00, 4,30]
4  avn    4  [15,00, 10,00, 4,30]
5  avn    3  [15,00, 10,00, 4,30]
6  psp    1  [17,00, 7,60, 14,30]
7  psp    3  [17,00, 7,60, 14,30]
8  psp    5  [17,00, 7,60, 14,30]
```

One more step to get you the desired output:

```
#use the row index%3 to select the element from the list under c_t column.
df.c_t=df.apply(lambda x: x.c_t[x.name%3],axis=1)

df
Out[761]: 
  type  n_b    c_t
0   sp    2  98,00
1   sp    2   0,00
2   sp    3  68,00
3  avn    2  15,00
4  avn    4  10,00
5  avn    3   4,30
6  psp    1  17,00
7  psp    3   7,60
8  psp    5  14,30
```